# Python - Stacking Cups?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to write a function ('def stackHeights') where you are suppose to take an argument a number of cups, and returns the maximum height of a stack that can be built with that number of cups. For example if you have 7 cups, you can build the stack of height 3, but you don't have enough for a stack of height 4, because you only have one cup for the bottom row and you need 4.

"Hint: build from top to bottom using a while.

Output:

```
>>> stackHeight (7) 
3
>>> stackHeight (3)
2 
>>> stackHeight (12) 
4
```

This is what I have right now:

```
def stackHeight(nCups):
    nCups = int(input())
    cups = {}
    for i in range(nCups):
        line = input().split()
        if line[0].isnumeric():
            cups[int(line[0])/2] = line[1]
        else:
            cups[int(line[1])] = line[0]
            print("\n".join([cups[k] for k in sorted(cups.keys())]))
```

What am I doing wrong? The code doesn't seem to run for some reason. Keep in mind that I'm still fairly new to programming, so sorry for the cluster.

Comment: Your program will be stopping and waiting for input whenever it reaches `input()`. You shouldn't have any calls to `input()` _inside_ your function.

Comment: You have two `input` statements in your function. The first only serves to overwrite your input argument and is therefore pointless and redundant. You have another in the loop. I dont see anything in your functions description requiring text input, so why have it?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few problems I notice with your code. First of all, you have `input()` way too many times, and `input()` will freeze the program whilst waiting for a user input. You probably want `input("string that tells the user what to put here")`. Also, you have a variable `nCups`, but `nCups` is being set to `input()`, so it is completely making the point of the variable useless. Also, if you want it how it is in your example, you don't want to `print()` in the loop. Another thing is that when you do `cups={}`, you are making it a dictionary, but you are later using an integer for the index, so you want a list [].

Answer (score 0):

You're referring to a sequence of numbers called the [Triangular Numbers](https://oeis.org/A000217), which has an equation to calculate the n-th number:

```
T(n) = n(n+1)/2
```

Using the quadratic formula you can invert this to:

```
T'(n) = (sqrt(8n+1)-1)/2
```

And thus your code will be:

```
def stackHeight(nCups):
    return ((8*nCups+1)**0.5-1) // 2
```

And testing:

```
>>> def stackHeight(nCups):
...     return ((8*nCups+1)**0.5-1)//2
...
>>> stackHeight(7)
3.0
>>> stackHeight(3)
2.0
>>> stackHeight(12)
4.0
```